# Vertical positioning for button in responsive design doesnt move

Tags: css, responsive-design, vertical-alignment

I am having a lot of trouble getting my button in a BigCommerce theme to vertically align to the bottom. Since it is a responsive design, absolute positioning doesn't quite get the work done. Unfortunately it is the only thing that seems to move the buttons at all; I've tried all sorts of methods with relative positions and the vertical position will not budge. It seems that the products are listed within a list that functions as a table.

Here is the css for the button itself. I added the stuff below "border" and have tried many different ways as well as tried changing display to inline-block.

```
.product-grid .ProductActionAdd .button {
 display:block;
 background: #424546;
 border: 1px solid #303334;
 position: relative; 
 vertical-alignment:bottom;
 bottom:0;

 }
```

I can provide css for the other parts as well. Below is basically what I'm trying to fix. Those with 1-line product names would have the "in stock" button moved up.

[image of buttons and problem](http://imgur.com/lVbR4nI)

Comment: This `vertical-alignment` should be `vertical-align`, only to correct the syntax, this does not solve your issue

Comment: Post your HTML in a jsFiddle or similar...

Comment: @Huangism is correct, and even then it will only work on table>table-cell or block>inline-block i believe.

Comment: Does the answer I posted not work?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YJ8tq/
Here's the snippet and css. As you can see, the html mostly involves referencing other files.

Answer (score 0):

Without the full HTML/CSS or a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) it's going to be difficult for me to provide you with the complete HTML/CSS solution, but here's what will fix the problem:

- Wrap the button and description inside of an element and set `position:relative` on that wrapper element
- Give the buttons the following style: `position: absolute; margin: 0 auto; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 5px;`
- Set the description to a fixed height and give the wrappers a fixed height

That should solve your issue. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/drR7r/)

Comment: Just tried and it actually shrank all the buttons to a 2px wide vertical line. Here's the html and css: http://jsfiddle.net/YJ8tq/